# Does the prediction ok or not in this case?

Tags: conv-neural-network

Would you please tell me if the prediction here is correct or not for the following code, it's a test code for CNN,
I'm using Jupyter, Tensorflow 2.9.0, and Keras 2.9.0

I hope someone can help me solve it soon

```
import math
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
########### PARAMETERS ##############
threshold = 0.90 # MINIMUM PROBABILITY TO CLASSIFY
#### LOAD THE TRAINNED MODEL 
model = load_model('model_trained.h5')
path = r'C:\Users\Issam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Digits-Classification-master\Weed_Detection\MyTestData\test9.jpg'
# Reading an image in default mode and creating subimages
i = Image.open (path)
width, height = i.size
print(width)
print(height)
L=0
T=0
R=width
B=height
imgOriginal= frame1
img = np.asarray(imgOriginal)
img = cv2.resize(img,(200, 200))
img = preProcessing(img)
cv2.imshow("Processed Image",img)
img = img.reshape(1,200,200,1)
frame1 = i.crop(((L, T, R, B/3)))
def preProcessing(img):
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
        img = img / 255
        return img
# Predict
predictions = model.predict(img)  
classIndex = np.argmax(predictions,axis=1) 
probVal = np.amax(predictions) 
if probVal > threshold:
    if classIndex == 0:
        item1 = "No_Weed"
        prob1=probVal
        print(item1, "Probability: ",probVal)
    elif classIndex == 1:
        item1 = "Weed"
        prob1=probVal
        print(item1, "Probability: ",probVal)
```

The Model Result like below

Model: "sequential"

---

## Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 196, 196, 60)      1560

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 192, 192, 60)      90060

max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 96, 96, 60)       0
)

conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 94, 94, 30)        16230

conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 92, 92, 30)        8130

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 46, 46, 30)       0
2D)

dropout (Dropout)           (None, 46, 46, 30)        0

flatten (Flatten)           (None, 63480)             0

dense (Dense)               (None, 500)               31740500

dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 500)               0

dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 1002

=================================================================
Total params: 31,857,482
Trainable params: 31,857,482
Non-trainable params: 0

---

None

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough points to comment, adding a comment as an answer.
It really is not possible to check the output of the model without actually knowing its architecture (especially the final layer). Would you be kind enough to do a `print(model.summary())` ?

Comment: thanks for your kind response, I've already updated my post and added the model.summary